# EF4.0 - Inserting related objects to database

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I'm trying Entity Framework 4.0 and here is *the* most simplified version of the case -

I have the following two related tables -

**Address**
Id
City

**Client**
Id
AddressId
Name

I've loaded the addresses in the ComboBox. All I want is to enter the Client name in the TextBox, select an Address from the ComboBox as the Client's Address and hit the Save Button. I want my Client to be saved in the Client table. Here's what i tried -

```
    /*loads Addresses to the ComboBox*/
    private void LoadData()
    {
        using (CAEntities ctx = ModelAccess.GetContext())
            this.AddressList = ctx.Addresses.ToList();
    }

    /*(tries) to insert the Client to the database*/
    private void Save()
    {
        /*here this.Client is the Client object that is instantiated & initialized   
          by previous code and this.Address is the SelectedItem of the ComboBox*/
        this.Client.Address = this.Address;
        using (CAEntities ctx = ModelAccess.GetContext())
        {
            ctx.Clients.AddObject(this.Client);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Julie Lerman in [Programming Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652028X) says that `...Because the
entities are joined, you can add either entity, and it will bring along the rest of the graph...` But what I'm having is an InvalidOperationException that says "The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null."
If I use -

```
this.Client.AddressId = this.Address.Id;
```

instead of -

```
this.Client.Address = this.Address;
```

the Client is inserted to database perfectly. But I think I'm also supposed to be able to relate Entities directly to each other, right?
I assumed that the problem is related to the separate context i'm creating. So i tried this -

```
    private void Save()
    {
        this.Client.Address = this.Address;
        using (CAEntities ctx = ModelAccess.GetContext())
        {
            ctx.Addresses.Attach(this.Address);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

but this time i'm getting an InvalidOperationException that says "An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context." So what is it that I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: because what you're grabbing with this.Client.Address is a value from the combo box, not the address object.  it is trying to create a new address object in the database and you can't assign that to the client until it is created.   that's why this.Client.AddressId works  you would have to instantiate the address with something like var Address = GetById(this.Client.AddressId and then set Client.Address = Address.

Comment: @Brian: i know what u suggest works, but i don't understand how is what i'm grabbing from the combo box a value, not an Address object? i set a list of Address object as it's data source, and i'm taking the currently `SelectedItem` as this.Address, and i'm getting the Id & City properties from that.

Comment: because it is the datasource.  A combo box holds a key value pair not an object.  So by assigning that key value pair as the address object back to the client, you're telling the db context to create a new address in the db, but it has to exist to save it to the client.  That is where the temporary entity key message is coming from.

Comment: @Brian: i really didn't get you. from xaml i set binding of the combobox's `SelectedItem` property to that Address in my ViewModel. so whenever the `SelectedItem` changes am i not supposed to get an Address object? `SelectedItem`, as mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.100%29, returns a `System.Object` and you can cast it to your custom object, am i right?

Comment: To a certain extent you are, but keep in mind what a combobox is and what it is going to return and the medium where you are using it (the view page).  It's just going to pass back a key value pair from the combobox.   That is what you have to work with.

Comment: @Brian: are we on the same page that it's in WPF? cuz you sound more like asp.net :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This should fix the problem:**

```
    using (CAEntities ctx = ModelAccess.GetContext())
    {
        ctx.Addresses.Attach(this.Address);
        this.Client.Address = this.Address;
        ctx.Clients.AddObject(this.Client);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Why does this work?**

The DbContext keeps track of objects that it's pulled down or that have been explicitly attached to it.  In your case, you were setting `this.Client.Address` to an object that the DbContext was not aware of.  In some cases, this will cause entity framework to insert both a new client row *and* a new address row, but in your case, due to some semantic detail I'm not privy to, it threw an obscure exception.

By attaching `this.Address` to the DbContext, entity framework understands that the Address already exists in the database, and that you are creating an association with an existing object when assigning it to `this.Client.Address`.

IMO, Entity Framework's semantics need to be better documented.  There are a lot of cases like these where a misleading or obscure exception is thrown.  For example when attaching objects, it's important to keep in mind that they are attached recursively.  If you were to in a new data context attach `this.Client` it would recursively attach `this.Client.Address` as well, and any other entities `this.Client` might reference.  For this reason, if you were to explicitly attach `this.Client` and then `this.Address` you would get an exception because the Address had been implicitly attached when you attached`this.Client`.

Comment: thanks a LOT brian, it did fix the problem :D but can you please elaborate a bit on what exactly goes wrong when i set `this.Client.Address = this.Address;` before attaching the Address.

Comment: i know `ObjectServices` keeps track of only `EntityObject`s that it is aware of. in my case only the Address object. and since the Client object is created within the code, the context is not aware of it. but when i assign `this.Client.Address = this.Address;` am i not creating a complete object graph relating the entities to each other? and then afterward when i attach the Address object shouldn't the context become aware of the Client object too, since it is now related to the Address object? so i still don't get that `...temporary EntityKey value...` exception. anyway, thank you again.

Comment: and i TOTALLY agree with your `better documentation` opinion. i see a lot of people who uses EF but very few of them have any idea what's happening under-the-hood.

Comment: If you want to see how the DbContext "sees" the entity, pass the entity to the `dataContext.Entry()` method and check its EntityState.  If it's `Detached` then the DbContext has no knowledge of it, even if it was originally pulled down by a previous DbContext.  The DbContext has to be told, by attaching the object, "Hey, this object already exists in the database."  That way when saving changes, the DbContext knows "This Address entity already exists in the database, there is no need to create a new one before inserting the Client row."